# How to copy .NET Framework Console Application subfolders to the release folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I was wondering if someone could please help me with something.

The main idea is that I want to have a .NET Framework Console App, which is build and packaged into a single file (an archive or something similar, like a jar file in the java world, containing all the referenced .dll files, sources files and additional project files) that i can deploy on another machine.

I've build an Console app using .NET 4.7.2 which is receiving data from a remote server and it pushes it to RabbitMQ. I use a .p12 file to authenticate to RMQ, which i keep stored in a sub-folder in my app called "Others".

When I run it from Visual Studio 2019 it works, but when I try either to release it and run it from that folder or to install it on my windows 10 machine it does not work anymore. It gives me the following exception :

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the path specified.
...
```

When I publish the app, via the publish window, I select an output folder and I get the following files and folders :

- (folder) Application Files
- (file) setup, type of file - Application.exe (.application)
- (file) ConsoleApp, type of file - Application Manifest (.application)
  The RabbitMQ .dll file, which contains the RabbitMQ Client is located inside the folder "Application Files\ConsoleApp_1_0_0_13" together with other .dll files and a subfolder ("XMLRequest") but does not contain the other subfolders of my project.
  I don't have the possibility to add these subfolders, where my .p12 key is located, i.e. "Others", in the publish screen of the application.

The other case when it does not work is when I to copy the whole "Release" subfolder into another location and just run the ConsoleApp.exe from there. I get the same error message.

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Packaging your app as a single .exe file**

If you want your .NET Framework Console App, to be packaged into a single file, then I would take a look at the nuget package `Costura.Fody`.  It will package up all the projects DLLs into a single .exe for you.  I use it all the time.

All you need to do is add the nuget package to your project like this:

```
PM> Install-Package Fody
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

and out will pop a single .exe

**Embedding Resource Files - Option #1**

If you want to include files in your deployment, what I have done in the past is embed them in the exe themselves and then extract them when the app runs.

To do this, add the files to your project as normal:

[image]

Then right-click the file and select "properties" and set the build action to be an "embedded resource".

[image]

This will alow you extract the file later on, when the program is running.  With this setup you could have any number of resource files setup in the app.

Then on startup of the app, you can extract the embedded resource to a file on disk using a function like this:

```
public static string GetEmbeddedResource(string resourceName)
{
    string resourceContents = "";

    try
    {
        string[] names = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

        string resource = "";
        foreach (string str in names)
        {
            if (str.ToLower().Contains(resourceName.ToLower()) == true)
            {
                resource = str;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resource) == false)
        {
            using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource), Encoding.Default))
            {
                resourceContents = sreader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return resourceContents;
}
```

with the usage of the above function looking like this:

```
var resource = GetEmbeddedResource("SomeFile.txt");
```

and then you can write the file to anywhere you need it on disk.

**Embedding Resource Files - Option #2**

The other option would be to copy the embedded resource to the output folder but then that means you wont have a single .exe file if you are manually copying this from machine to machine.

[image]

**Embedding Resource Files - Option #3**

If you are using ClickOnce technology to deploy your app, which it looks like you are, then when you go to the publish tab, if you select the "Application Files"

[image]

you can then choose which files to include in the deployment as seen here.

[image]

Comment: Multiple solutions, first one to package app in a single file, second one to include files into the output directory, big thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

1. Open the project in Visual Studio
2. Go to Solution Explorer --> Click on Project --> Click "Show All Files" menu in Solution Explorer Menu
3. All the folders in your project will appear with dotted border in your project files tree
4. Right Click your folder and click "Include In Project"
5. Navigate to your file by expanding your folder in Solution Explorer
6. Right click file and click "Properties"
7. In Properties windows select "Copy always" for "Copy to Output Directory"

Performing above steps will cause Visual Studio to copy your entire folder to output (Debug and Release) directory.

There is also another option to publish required files during build and release process. Right click your required files and click properties. In the properties window set appropriate value for Build Action property to the value that you need. Following documentation describes when to use which Build Action Values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes, this is the solution for including files to the release output folder, thanks ! I accepted the other answer as it contains also a solution on how to package the app into a single file.